# How to use network policy to allow access to pods only from a specific namespace to another in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, policy

How can I achieve that when obviously you can not use `spec.namespaceSelector` in the netpol?

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-from-ns-netpol
  namespace: special-ns
spec:
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      kubernetes.io/metadata.name: app
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:     
          matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: cka-exam
```

So, this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the problem here: you can use `namespaceSelector` in the `ingress` block; isn't that exactly what you want? You need to use a label selector rather than a namespace name, but that's relatively easy to deal with (just label the source namespace appropriately).

Comment: Try this [doc](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/07-allow-traffic-from-some-pods-in-another-namespace.md) may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy this chooses pods based on their label. I want to choose them based on the namespace they belong to. And make them available to other pods again based on the namespace they belong to.  For example the pods of the `special-ns` namespace should be available to pods from the `app` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API resource definition you've provided does not appear to be schema compliant. The [NetworkPolicySpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#networkpolicyspec-v1-networking-k8s-io) in Kubernetes v1.26 shows that the following fields are allowed: `[policyTypes, podSelector, egress, ingress]`.

I recommend taking a look at the [Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) documentation.

When you define a Network Policy, you assign it to a Namespace. You can then narrow that Network Policy to only apply to select Pods (in that Namespace) using the `.spec.podSelector` property. As the documentation states, "An empty `podSelector` selects all pods in the namespace."

This means if you want block all ingress traffic to the Pods in Namespace `special-ns`, you would assign the Network Policy to the `special-ns` Namespace and leave the `.spec.podSelector` property empty so it selects all of the Pods in `special-ns`. Without any `ingress` rules defined, the resource would be the [Default deny all ingress traffic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-traffic) definition.

You then use the `ingress` property to define the restrictions, or rules, on *where* that incoming traffic can come from. It looks like your existing definition is correct, so ingress traffic will only be allowed from Pods that exist in the Namespace `cka-exam`.

```yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-from-ns-netpol
  namespace: special-ns
spec:
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:     
          matchLabels:
            kubernetes.io/metadata.name: cka-exam
```